# Why is reinstalling Ruby 1.8.7 failing

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I tried to reinstall Ruby 1.8.7 using RVM after having troubles with Homebrew. I reinstalled Homebrew and RVM, and I have Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 working fine.

One of my projects uses 1.8.7 so when I used:

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```

I got:

```
The requested url does not exist(22):'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.0.9.tgz'
Checking fallback: ftp://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.0.9.tgz
Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.0.9.tgz
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

There has been an error while trying to fetch rubygems. 
Halting the installation.
```

I tried to do:

```
rvm get stable
rvm get head 
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Which I found on another Stack Overflow question with a similar error, but it's obviously a bit different.

I run:

- RVM 1.22.9 (stable)
- Homebrew 0.9.4
- Mac OSX 10.8.4

Comment: This looks like a RVM error, not a Ruby problem. I'd suggest talking to the RVM authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing essentially the same error with a chef deploy of rvm under ubuntu - ruby 1.8.7 refuses to complete installation (the ruby is there, but no gem, etc) due to a problem with 'rubygems-2.0.9.tgz'

Edited to add - if you run 'rvm rubygems 2.0.7' (latest that seems to be really available right now) it seems to work.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. It keep seeking for rubygems-2.0.9

Comment: sorry - here's the sequence that should work: `rvm install 1.8.7; rvm use 1.8.7; rvm rubygems 2.0.7`

Comment: mpapis' comment shows an even simpler way - I hadn't noticed rvm had a --rubygems option!

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue with rubygems release process - https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2212 and https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/651

For next time it happens you can specify which version of rubygems to use when installing ruby with rvm like this:

```
rvm install 1.8.7 --rubygems 2.0.8
```